# Как центрировать сайт?

Tags: html, css

Скажите, как правильно центрировать сайт? Буду рад, если сделают полный код к примеру.
`float left` и т.д. не идёт, т.к. устанавливается от экрана. Следовательно, если экран 1920х1080 и 1024-1024, то эффект разный будет. Прошу помощи, о великие мастера.
Спасибо.как возле етого центрального контейнера тогда сделать ну сразу же ещё 1 маленький контейнер- спарава.

Comment: Спасибо.как возле етого центрального контейнера тогда сделать ну сразу же ещё 1 маленький контейнер- спарава.

Comment: @MagicStyle, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно контент сайта помещают в контейнер с заданной шириной, которому боковые margins делают `auto`:

```
<div id="container" style="width:960px;margin:0 auto;">
    блоки сайта
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить ширину сайта, а потом поставить по центру. Делается так:

```
<style>
.wrap {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;} /*Отступ сверху и снизу - 0, слева и справа автоматически, т.е. по центру*/
</style>
<div class="wrap">Это блок обязательно будет по центру</div>
```

Comment: это чем-то отличается от моего, более раннего ответа?

Comment: Нет. Разве что подробностью. Когда я набирал, твоего сообщения еще не было.

Comment: вы ещё подеритесь, горячие финские парни :-D